# Is it possible to assign different page layouts to an object on different apps of one org?

Tags: lightning-apps, page-layout, object, pagelayoutassignment

I have a quick question please.

This is the situation:

I am connected to an org.

Let's assume this org have 2 apps using the same object.

Is it possible to use a different layout for that object in each app for the same profile ?

I know that layouts are assigned by profile and I am asking if they could get assigned by apps ?

If this is not possible should I understand that the term "App" used on a salesforce org is just a way of organizing the different object tabs of the SF org and not an independent entity.

(Am not a native speaker, so i am sorry if my English is shaky)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question:

> Is it possible to use a different layout for that object in each app for the same profile ?

The answer is both **Yes** and **No**.

**Yes** -- if you are using Record Types for your object. Record Types let you assign different page layout for same object to same profile

**No** -- if you are not using Record Types, then you can only assign one page layout per object to any profile

> I know that layouts are assigned by profile and I am asking if they could get assigned by apps ?

You cannot assign page layouts by **apps**, but only using one of the combinations as explained above

---

For more details, refer to these help documentations:

- [Assign Page Layouts to Profiles or Record Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layoutassign.htm&type=5)
- [Assign Page Layouts from a Customize Page Layout or Record Type Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=layouts_assigning.htm&type=5)